# Get latest Build from Serverless API

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I would like to update a single Asset in my serverless Service. I know how to create a new Asset Version with the new content. But, creating a new Build and a new Deployment is VERY tedious.

My idea was to find the most recent Build and then "swap out" the one Asset Version I want to change and send that back to the API as a new Build.

However, the Build API is paged so it seems a bit fiddly to find the most recent Build since I have to potentially iterate over page after page of Builds.

Is there an easier way to get the most recent Build for a given Service?

As an aside, it would be cool to have an endpoint that would Deploy the most recent versions of all Functions and Assets in the Service. Basically, the programmatic equivalent of pushing the Deploy button in the Console.

Comment: It appears that the results are ordered with newest first. I'm not sure I can rely on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [environment](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/serverless-api/api/environment) has a property called `BuildSid` that is the Sid of the latest build.

If it helps, I wrote the [assets plugin for the Twilio CLI](https://www.twilio.com/docs/labs/serverless-toolkit/assets-plugin) that allows you to upload a new asset to a service and deploy. The [code can be found here](https://github.com/twilio-labs/serverless-toolkit/blob/main/packages/plugin-assets/src/upload.js). I've been meaning to extract the code to a library to make it easier to use, but perhaps you can use this to help write your version of it.

Comment: I hadn't looked at the Environment too much. That's helpful. And thank you for the code. I'm having a lot of trouble getting the right JSON to the "create a Build" endpoint. I ended up having to send it as multipart form data which doesn't seem correct at all.

Comment: We also have a library, [@twilio-labs/serverless-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@twilio-labs/serverless-api) that has implemented the API. You can either use it, or [check out the source code for creating a build here](https://github.com/twilio-labs/serverless-toolkit/blob/main/packages/serverless-api/src/api/builds.ts#L96-L134).

Comment: Thanks. Late yesterday, I realized something. Twilio is not a JSON API. It returns JSON but it expects www-urlencoded form data or multiparty form data in the request. I swear I’ve never seen that mentioned in the documentation. It’s always abstracted out by the various SDKs or CLI clients. I think I’d have it in big bold letters at the top of every page of API docs.

Comment: That's great feedback, thanks! We tend to rely on the libraries, but you're right, that should be clear. I will share that with the team.